# how to get from jid & to jid using smack and java?

Tags: java, facebook, chat, smack

By using below code I can only get  from userId but n't to userId.

```
public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {

         if ((message != null) && (message.getBody() != null)) {

            System.out.println(chat.getParticipant());

          }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created One Custom Message Listener which is intialized at a time when you have successfully connect to the Server as: messageListener = new MyMessageListener(); and the Custom MessageListener contains the code as :

class MyMessageListener implements MessageListener {

```
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Chat chat, Message message) {
        String from = message.getFrom();
        String body = message.getBody();
        System.out.println(String.format(
                "Received message '%1$s' from %2$s", body, from));
    }

}
```

May be it's help you.